# Removing Fax Field from Magento Template

Tags: checkout, magento-1, template

I know this question has been asked previously, but I tried a few steps to remove the Fax field from my onepage checkout page and it is still visible.

The Magento settings in **System** -> **Configuration** -> **Design** lists "default" as package and "ves_fashion" as Standard.

I navigated to     `test/app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

and removed the fax from the template. I also did this for:

```
test/app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
test/app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
test/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
test/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

My structure looks like this, which i think its odd because I have multiple ves_fashion folders:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default
app/design/frontend/default/blank
app/design/frontend/default/default
app/design/frontend/default/iphone
app/design/frontend/default/modern
app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/
app/design/frontend/ves_fashion/etc/
app/design/frontend/ves_fashion/layout/
app/design/frontend/ves_fashion/locale/
app/design/frontend/ves_fashion/template/
app/design/frontend/ves_fashion/demo2/
app/design/frontend/ves_fashion/demo3/
app/design/frontend/ves_fashion/demo4/
```

Any idea how I can finally remove the fax field from the onepage checkout page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to enable the template hints, login to admin go to `system >> configurations >> developers (under Advance section on left bottom)`
now change the `Current Configuration Scope` (a dropdown at top left of the configuration page) to your specific store view to see template hints selection option and refresh your frontend and you will find the exact file path that is being used.

**Edited:**

For restricted appearance of hints, you will find an ip field as the top input field on the same page, if your store is live please enter your ip (comma separated ip's in case of more than one).

Comment: Thanks - is this only visible to me as a magenta admin who is logged in?

Comment: updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

So MTM gave good advice on where to find the file path, which you should definitely follow. However, the file you need is:

/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/*YOURTHEME*/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

Where *YOURTHEME* is presumably ves_fashion. (it looks like you already looked here but this is where it is).

To remove it, you need to comment out the entire input box:

```
<!--<div class="field">
    <label for="billing:fax"><?php echo $this->__('Fax') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" name="billing[fax]" value="<?php echo $this- >escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getFax()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Fax') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('fax') ?>" id="billing:fax" />
      </div>
</div>-->
```

Save and re-upload. I just did it on my site and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

To remove company, fax field from magento onepage checkout 1.9
reminder: company field and fax field etc. most be removed from guest and registered customer and in billing and shipping (if you wish to remove)

1. for removing company, fax etc field in billing information: open `app/design/frontend/rwd/template/persistant/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

find the line: 
`<div class="field">
<label for ="billing:company"><? php echo.......`

and replace it with this:
`<div class="field" style="display:none">
<label for ="billing:company"><? php echo.......`

company field should be gone stay in this file and change fax field the same if you wish.

now for shipping go to: 
`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml`

1. again do the same to remove company, fax field etc in shipping: look for the file: 
   `<div class="field"> (remember this file name is located above the field name you wish to remove, do the same as the first lesson: 
   <div class="field" style="display:none">
   <label for ="shipping:company"><? php echo.......`

Answer (score 0):

You Can remove it by using css.

Add the following code in your `style.css` and it will remove the Fax field only from your Checkout page in frontend.

> .checkout-index-index .field[name="shippingAddress.fax"] {
>       display: none; }